# Unable to Start Datanode and Namenode in Hadoop 2.8.1

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop2

Trying to Run Hadoop on Local Server but Unable to do so.

Getting Error when running command ./start-dfs.sh

```
17/08/25 11:58:08 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/piyush/hadoop-2.8.1/logs/hadoop-piyush-namenode-Ubuntu.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/piyush/hadoop-2.8.1/logs/hadoop-piyush-datanode-Ubuntu.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0] 0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/piyush/hadoop-2.8.1/logs/hadoop-piyush-secondarynamenode-Ubuntu.out
17/08/25 11:58:33 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform is just a warning and u can ignore it, Execute the below command to check whether namenode, secondary namenodes are running

> ps aux | grep -i "namenode\|datanode"

If you don't find any hadoop process running, check the log files.